# Apache configuration / Catch-all subdomain / Specific subdomain exception

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

Startting with some simple domain setup :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName site.com
        ServerAlias *.site.com
        DocumentRoot /path/to/site.com
        <Directory /path/to/site.com>
                AllowOverride all
                Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).site.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com$1 [R=301]
        RailsEnv production
</VirtualHost>
```

So I'm pretty happy, anything put before my domain will be removed and my urls will always be clean : http://site.com

Cool!

** BUT **

I'd like to set a specific subdomain (an exception in that case) which would point to another site on the same server (another folder, another slightly different apache config, etc…)

This setup above will always precedes the one I would do for my 'exception' dubdomain.
How could I reach the goal described ? Catch-all apache setup with one (or some more) subdomain setup exceptions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add you  configuration for desired subdomain above this code, it should help.

Comment: Indeed. but the point is, for some setup organizations reasons, i have a separate vhost file for each domain I set on this server >> it does not work if I do an 'add above'. My new domain being alphabetically before the one that should catch all, it does not work… This whole thing seems to me a little bit too randomly working, there might be something more accurate than the "add above" way